# SQLITE file is encrypted or is not a database

Tags: sqlite

I have a huge problem... I am developing a desktop app with SQLite but during the copy/paste process I lost power and the process was terminated so the database was lost. However, I found a way to recover it but the database is encrypted. When I try to open a connection using `conn.Open();` I get the error: "SQLITE is encrypted or is not a database". If I try to open it with DB Browser for SQLite it asks me a SQLCipher encryption password so it seems to me that data is lost.

Is there any default password?
Why did this happen and how can I prevent it from happening again?
What can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you actually encrypt it? If not, see the part after the "or".

Comment: I didn't encrypt it. The connection string is             
 m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Baza.sqlite;Version=3;Read Only=False;Journal Mode=Off"); 
and it was working perfectly fine until it was deleted. I found it by name and it says that is sqlite file. It doesn't have sens.. It is a database and is not encrypted but somehow become encrypted

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 15):

Also check that **SQLite version you're "connecting" with aligns with the DB file version**.

For example, here's a DB file written by SQLite version 3+:

```
$ file foobar.db 
foobar.db: SQLite 3.x database, last written using SQLite version 3027002
```

And here I also have 2 versions of sqlite:

```
$ sqlite -version
2.8.17
$ sqlite3 -version
3.27.2 2019-02-25 16:06:06 bd49a8271d650fa89e446b42e513b595a717b9212c91dd384aab871fc1d0alt1
```

Obviously in hindsight, opening `foobar.db` with sqlite version 2 will fail, yielding the same error message:

```
$ sqlite foobar.db 
Unable to open database "foobar.db": file is encrypted or is not a database
```

But all is good with the correct version:

```
$ sqlite3 foobar.db
SQLite version 3.27.2 2019-02-25 16:06:06
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> 
sqlite> .databases 
main: /tmp/foobar.db
sqlite>
```

The error message is a catch-all, simply meaning that the file format was not recognized.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, finally found a solution that works so posting the answer if anybody will have same trouble as I did..

First of all, use good recover software. For repairing the database I found 3 solutions that work without backup :

1. Open corrupted database using DB Browser an Export Database to SQL. Name it however you want. Then, create new database and import database from SQL.
2. There is software that repairs corrupted databases. Download one and use it to repair the database.
3. Download "sqlite3" from sqlite.org and in command line navigate to folder where "sqlite3" is unzipped. Then try to dump the entire database with .dump, and use those commands to create a new database:

   ```
   sqlite3 corrupt_table_name.sqlite ".dump" | sqlite3 new.sqlite
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I was trying to access a db dump in another system compared to compared to where it was obtained. When I tried to open on a dev machine, it threw the reported error in this thread:

```
$ sqlite3 db_dump.sqlite .tables
Error: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

This turned out to be due to the differences in the sqlite version between those systems. This dev system version was 3.6.20.

The version on the production system was 3.8.9. Once I had the sqlite3 upgraded to same version, I was able to access all its data. I am just showing below the tables are displayed as expected:

```
# sqlite3 -version
3.8.9
# sqlite3 db_dump.sqlite .tables
capture               diskio                transport     
consumer              filters               processes
```

This error is rather misleading to begin with, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you've interacted with the database at some point while specifying `journal_mode = WAL`, and then later try to use the database from a client that does not support `WAL` (< v3.7.0), this error can also come up.

[As noted in the SQLite documentation under Backwards Compatibility](https://sqlite.org/wal.html), to resolve that without having to recreate the database, explicitly set the journal mode to `DELETE`:

```
PRAGMA journal_mode=DELETE;
```

Comment: Based on what you said I just deleted the journal file and now my db opens. Thanks for that tip.

Answer (score 0):

Your database did not become encrypted (this is only one of the two options in the error message).

Your data recovery tool did not recover the correct data; what you have in the file is something else.

You have to restore the database file from the backup.

Comment: I tried with two different recovery tools ( one of them is officialy suggested by Microsoft ) and found 3 same databases ( name of database is "Baza" so I am 100% sure it is the database and is SQLite file ). Tried with all of them and with all I get the same error...

But, however, do you have any other idea how to backup it ?

Comment: SQLite databases are just filed; you can just make copies (while they're not open).

Comment: sorry, you are perfectly right. It seems that database is corrupted. After 2 day research result is following : 
- Opening database with DB SQLite browser -> Error message : File is encrypted or is not a database. 
- I made a contact with Zetetic support ( SQLCipher developers ) - answer is that is not possible that database got encrypted by itself. 
- Trying to open database with command line and sqlite3 : same error message.
- Tried opening it with XVI32 HEX editor. Also, opened few databases that work fine and found a big difference in header.

Comment: -when I try to run it using "sqlite3_analyzer" I get a message : " Database disk image is malformed

Do you have any idea how to recover database ? 

If I open it with notepad++ there isn't readable format , strange characters appear.

Comment: As I said, you have to restore it from a backup. (How well that works depends on how many backups you have …)

Comment: But the problem is there is no backup. Is there any other solution ? At the moment I am digging with 2 other recovery tools in hope that I will get normal database. But in case that I don't, is there any other option ?

Comment: Sorry; asking for a third time does not change the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with sqlcipher version upgrade in my case, Whenever I update my pod it automatically upgrade the sqlcipher and the error occurred.

For a quick fix just manually add the SDK instead of Pod install. And for a proper solution use this link [GitHub Solution](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher/issues/233)