# Setting the password by code to a Sqlite2 database on Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using: Visual Studio Community 2015 + C# + Entity Framework 6.2 + SQlite2

I know how to protect a SQlite database as I use the below code to attach password to it :

```
using (sqlite2 = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=ModuleUserDB.db"))
{
    //Set password
    sqlite2.SetPassword("this is my password");
}
```

But this doesn't work with Entity Framework.

I read this post 
[How to in-code supply the password to a connection string in an ADO.Net Entity Data Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170118/how-to-in-code-supply-the-password-to-a-connection-string-in-an-ado-net-entity-d)

but I can't figure out the solution for my case

- DbContext name: `ModuleUserDBEntities`
- Database name: `ModuleUserDB.db`

Trying to modify the constructor with:

```
public partial class ModuleUserDBEntities : DbContext
{
    public ModuleUserDBEntities() : base("name=ModuleUserDBEntities")
    {
        // Set the password of the database
        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\;Initial Catalog=ModuleUserDB.db;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=myownpassword";
    }
}
```

But Visual Studio gets stuck.

What is the simplest connection string to use for this case?

Comment: According to [this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/) there is no username in the connection string. And please use a better problem description than  "Visual Studio gets stucks". If there is an exception provide the entire exception detail.

Comment: @Crowcoder Just Visual Studio gets stucks with this info on the Inmediate Window: Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'WpfApplication1.App..ctor'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'WpfApplication1.App.InitializeComponent'

Answer (score 2):

Give `ChangePassword` method a try.Sample :

```
   using (sqlite2 = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=ModuleUserDB.db"))
   {
    sqlite2.Open();  //You must open the connection first
    sqlite2.ChangePassword("password here"); 
   }
```

Comment: How does changing the password resolve the connection string issue? Also you code has errors.

Comment: `ChangePassword` method changes password if there's an existing password, if there isn't,it sets the password :)

Comment: Yeah but how will that help Entity Framework connect?

Comment: My answer answer only `How to set password for sqlite` , isn't that what OP is asking for ?

Comment: That's not the way I read it. OP says "I know how to protect a SQlite database..."

Comment: yes, but he also said that his code doesn't work with entityframework....I am not sure if mine will work with entityframework either, let's wait for the OP's response :)

Comment: @zackraiyan thanks for the support, with youre code I get "System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteExcepcio "File is not a database not an error" Error code 26"

Comment: Is that the error ? It makes no sense..recheck the error..I assume it should be `File is not a database or is encrypted` or something like that

Comment: I hope my code helps you and if it does,mark it as the answer..And about the error you are getting,[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44161713/sqlite-file-is-encrypted-or-is-not-a-database) will solve it

Comment: @zackraiyan the error is the same, "File is not a database not an error" Error code 26" and I opened the SQLite database using a portable viewer and the database never gets encrypted. I will keep trying, thanks for the support.

Comment: @zackraiyan Your code work but for a database outside the Model - Entity Framework. Once I protect the data base with the code the others parts of the program (list records by example) didn´t work anymore. Thanks anyway, I read a lot of tutorials on these days and it seems complicated to use SQlite with password protection on Entity Framework